# eclipse: rebuild a project and all libraries

Tags: eclipse, java

I'm creating a Java project which includes a few libraries written by myself. However these libraries are not finished and sometimes require some edits. Because I'm working by myself, I find this more efficient than finishing all libraries perfectly before using them in my project.

My question is: is it possible to automatically rebuild a modified library when building the project which uses it?

Subquestion: what is the optimal configuration for my purposes? Should I export libraries as jar and copy them into the final project or should I configure buildpaths of my project to retrieve them in their respective folders?

Subsubquestion: is it correct to use .jar libraries in the same way that one uses dynamic libraries in c++?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Eclipse set to "build automatically", it'll take care of rebuilding the library projects whenever you make changes, as you go along. You should set your client program to depend on either the Eclipse projects (if doing everything inside Eclipse) or the Maven artifacts (if using m2e). I strongly prefer using Maven for all my Java builds, but it might be overkill for something small. Whatever you do, don't manually export and reimport the libraries.

All libraries in Java are dynamic, and a C++ `.so` or `.dll` is the basic equivalent.

Comment: Would I need everytime to export library as .jar or would it do it automatically? Up to now I always had to do it manually from menu File->Export

Comment: @HAL9000 Then your dependency setup is wrong. You should have both projects in the same workspace and tell Eclipse that one project depends on the other. If you're doing this manually (without Maven), it's in project properties->Project References.

Comment: Then I should add the library project in Project References and remove the .jar from Java Build Path. Is it correct?

Comment: I added the project in Project References and also in Build Path Projects. Now I see changes made inside the library (new methods etc), however, having removed the compiled jar from Java Build Path->Libraries, I get a runtime classNotFoundException. I still cannot realize if and how to automatically create a .jar when building final project.

Comment: For the final export build, you will need the File->Export. Handling this sort of thing is a good reason to use a build system like Maven.